# Why "require" keyword is followed by an "instance variable"?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and reading a piece of code. I don't understand this line:

```
require @a_variable
```

In my limited knowledge on Ruby, "require" is used to import modules, classes, or whatever stuff in other files. What is the usage there? I browsed a lot but can't find an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the thing. You have to pass a string to `require`. If that's a string literal or an expression which evaluates to a string doesn't matter.

```
require 'set'
```

or

```
set = 'set'
require set
```

is equivalent

Comment: I got it. If that "@a_variable" contains a path string then it makes sense.